# Fantasy book read in 1983-84 with jugglers and circus performers travelling through levels of a mountain, one is a prince and does not know it,

Tags: story-identification

Can you help me find a book from 83 or 84 which had four or five characters traveling as circus performers. One of them was a Prince but did not know it (amnesia) and there was juggling and sword swallowing and shape-shifters.  The prince then made his way up levels of a mountain to meet his mother, the Queen at the top. I think his brother was trying to stop him). I think its Prince of something?

Answer (score 15):

Robert Silverberg's 1980 novel [Lord Valentine's Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majipoor_series) could be it. The hero is the rightful ruler, affected by amnesia, and works as a juggler. There is a long trip up the mountain the castle sits on.

[image]

[Here](http://www.tor.com/2008/12/05/sciencefantasy/)'s a good summary:

> At the beginning of the first book, we meet the character of
>   Valentine, a wandering soul whose memories beyond the past few weeks
>   are little more than a gray haze.  At the same time, the world of
>   Majipoor is celebrating the ascension of a new Coronal, the supreme
>   ruler of the world.  As is tradition, the new Coronal is touring the
>   continents of Majipoor in the Grand Processional, which can often take
>   several years because of the planet’s size.  The new Coronal also
>   happens to be named Valentine, though it’s a very common name.
>
> Coming back to the first Valentine (the wandering soul with hazy
>   memories who shall hereafter be referred to as Wandering Valentine),
>   he and a newfound friend soon find themselves joining forces in a
>   nearby city with a traveling troupe of jugglers.  While they’re there,
>   Lord Valentine happens to pass through the city as part of his Grand
>   Processional.  Wandering Valentine catches a glimpse of Lord Valentine
>   and experiences an inexplicable and smoldering anger.  Gradually, we
>   learn that Wandering Valentine has been robbed of most of his
>   memories, has had his true body stolen from him, and that he is the
>   rightful Coronal of Majipoor.  The Lord Valentine parading across
>   Majipoor is an imposter, living inside Wandering Valentine’s body. 
>   When Wandering Valentine comes to grips with the realities of his
>   situation and his identity, he and his band of companions embark upon
>   a quest that takes them across the sprawling lands of Majipoor in an
>   effort to reclaim his lost throne.

More from the wikipedia article:

The mountain:

> Alhanroel is home to Castle Mount, a huge peak taller than Earth's
>   Mount Everest. Using force fields and atmosphere generators this
>   mountain has bucolic climate and many beautiful and wonderful cities.
>   At the top is the Coronal's Castle, which is referred to as "Lord
>   (current Coronal's) Castle". Since each Coronal is expected to add a
>   room or structure to the Castle, it is huge indeed.

Shapeshifters:

> The original race occupying Majipoor. They were none too pleased when
>   humans began colonizing the planet, and a smoldering guerrilla war
>   lasted for many centuries before the Coronal Lord Stiamot rounded up
>   and evicted the Metamorphs from Alhanroel. Normally bipedal, with flat
>   faces and green/grey skin, the Shapeshifters have the ability to mimic
>   virtually any bipedal race. When so disguised, they are virtually
>   indistinguishable from the real thing. This aided them greatly in
>   their struggles with Human colonists early in Majipoor's history.
>   Eventually, techniques were devised to detect Metamorphs, and they
>   were confined largely to a vast reservation on Zimroel. But the
>   intelligent beings have never stopped dreaming of a day when they
>   would retake the planet from the various other sentient species which
>   now inhabit it.

Comment: This was my immediate thought too. It wasn't his brother, but some kind of shape-shifter that had taken on his form and usurped his place.

Comment: One of the worst covers ever?

Comment: @o0'. I still have my copy of this print of Lord Valentine's Castle. Yea, the cover screams 1970's but I actually like the colorful art. I think it draws you into the book's blend of sci-fi & fantasy in the world of Majipoor. Even if the dude on the cover does look like one of the singers from the Bee-Gees wearing too tight red pants. My wife took one look at the cover & thought I was reading soft-core porn fantasy fiction. :-)